# Adding Module through code

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master workbook containing a macro which opens another workbook containing a demand forecast. The workbook opened through the macro is downloaded from a customer portal and is all new every day without possibility of editing it beforehand.

The macro then loops through the information and creates new readable and more intuitive worksheets. However, on a few of these worksheets I would like to add some event-driven code to give tooltips when mousing over or selecting cells.

Is there any possibility (without installing add-ons from vanilla Excel 2010) to add code to worksheet objects created during a macro?

The layout of the processed workbook is more or less static, so I was wondering if I should create a template file and then copy the input into it. That would allow me to have coded the events before data is added. Is this the best possibility?

Comment: Looks like you can do this: `Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Import ("c:\MyFolder\MyFileName.bas")` ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, appreciated. Although I ended up creating a template file since that was easier (for me) to create, test and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan pointed out, you could use Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject to programmatically add code modules to a workbook.  But doing this requires more lenient Macro security settings (which are set to untrusted, by default) and this is *not recommended.*

When I have to do something similar, I use three workbooks:

1. The data containing workbook

   - This book has no macro functionality
2. A template workbook containing the necessary macros
3. A macro enabled workbook to facilitate the transition.

Use workbook #3 to open workbook #1 and copy its data into workbook #2.  Save a copy of workbook #2 and close it.  Repeat this process as necessary.

It isn't the prettiest solution, but it keeps your code modular.

Comment: That is exactly what I ended up doing. I had to program some events that would be executed on the imported data's worksheets. I put those in a template macro-enabled workbook and copy the import data into a copy of this template before the data is cleaned up.